# CSV to DataTable Column constrained to be unique exception

Tags: c#, csv, datatable

I use the following code that convert CSV file to DataTable:

```
    public OverrideTableDataSet ConvertCSVtoDataTable(out OverrideTableDataSet dt, string csvFile)
    {
        Int32 num;
        dt = new OverrideTableDataSet();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(csvFile))
        {
            string[] headers = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
            foreach (string header in headers)
            {
                if(!dt.OverrideDataTable.Columns.Contains(header))
                {
                    dt.OverrideDataTable.Columns.Add(header);
                }
            }

            while(!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                string[] rows = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
                DataRow dr = dt.OverrideDataTable.NewRow();
                for (int i = 0; i < headers.Length; i++)
                {
                    rows[i] = rows[i].Replace("\\", "").Replace("\"", "");
                    dr[i] = Int32.TryParse(rows[i], out num);
                }
                dt.OverrideDataTable.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
        }

        return dt;
    }
```

And i get the following exception on runtime:

**Column 'UniqueId' is constrained to be unique.  Value '1' is already present.**

Why do i get this exception?

Note: This is how the data stored in the CSV file:

```
UniqueId    Data1   Data1   Data2   
0           FALSE    1       1   
1           FALSE    0       1   
2           FALSE    0       3   
3           FALSE    7       3
```

Comment: Have you run your code in debugger? I think you will know what went wrong with few breakpoints.

Comment: Yes, the problem is in the following line: dt.OverrideDataTable.Rows.Add(dr); - in the first time its ok, but in the second time i get the exception

Comment: Do you understand what the exception means?

Comment: It seems it trying to insert the same row.

Comment: No. It is saying you are inserting a new row with the same "UniqueId", this is not allowed because column "UniqueId" is constrained to be unique.